# Missed the MyOpenID demise; account lost forever?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, user-accounts, myopenid, metadata

Is there any way to get my old account + metadata back if I have lost an account ties to MyOpenID?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to the support center at https://stackoverflow.com/contact and provide your account information and email address.  They will likely be able to provide you with a process to regain access as long as you still have access to the email the account is currently associated with.