# Merge Data Explorer accounts with defunct OpenID provider

Tags: support, login, data-explorer

I've lost access to this account: https://data.stackexchange.com/users/46/quassnoi because I was using now defunct quassnoi.myopenid.com to authorize on it and never added other OpenId providers.

However I do have both quassnoi.myopenid.com and Google OpenID linked to my Stack Overflow account.

Is there a way I could retrieve my Data Explorer account?

Comment: Related: [Missed the MyOpenID demise; account lost forever?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/235192)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: unfortunately, Data Explorer does not have the contact form, and if I use my profile links on those on other sites, they don't pass validation.

Comment: The contact form goes to the same people everywhere. Just use one on a different site. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: the account links don't pass validation: http://i.snag.gy/NT4YG.jpg

Comment: Ah, make it a generic contact; merging accounts doesn't work at all on data.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: ok, thanks, will try